# Bell-Shaped functions parametrization

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives, roots

While doing some exercises from a supplement to Rudin's *"Principles of Mathematical Analysis"*, I have stumbled upon the following interesting problem:

> Notice that $\frac{A}{(Bx+C)^2+1}$ and $Ae^{-(Bx+c)^2}$ are examples of classes of Ball-Shaped functions which depend on three real parameters each. Can there exist a class of Bell-Shaped functions that depends on more than three parameters?

First of all I shall provide my definition of Bell-Shaped function:

> **Definition**: $f: R \rightarrow R$ is said to be a *Bell-Shaped* function iff:
>
> - $f \in C^{+ \infty}(\Bbb R)$ ($f$ is smooth)
> - $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0$
> - $f^{(n)}$ has exactly n zeros (let them be denoted in ascending order by $\{z_n^i\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$)

**MY ATTEMPT**:

I have tried using vector spaces, but I immediately realized that a class of same-form Bell-Shaped functions at most constitute an affine subspace (and I am not completely sure of that).

Then I started finding necessary conditions for $f$ to be a Bell-Shaped function, e.g.:

- $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f^{(n)}(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f^{(n)}(x) = 0$
- $z_n^i$ is an inversion point for $f^{(n)}$

However, even this time i didn't find anything useful in order to solve the problem.

Finally, I begun playing with the functions given as examples and i noticed that the parameters seemed to control specific elements of the graphs:

- $A$ defines the maximum height (in absolute value) reached by $f$
- $B$ defines the width of the central Bell
- $C$ defines the position of the point of maximum height

Therefore, I am now inclined to think that 3 is actually the maximum number of parameters, but I have no idea on how to prove that, or on how to rigorously define $A,B,C$.

As always, any form of help is highly appreciated!